# How to add text in a multiline textbox?

Tags: c#

I have to add details of my file into a multiline textbox. But all the details are getting added in a single line in the text box and not in a vertical sequence. I used Environment.NewLine and also used "\r\n", but it's not of any help. I have ticked the multiline text box in a Windows Forms form and also set it to true but to no avail.

My line of code is like this:

```
m_Txt.Multiline = true;

m_Txt.Text = fileInfo.m_Title + "\r\n" + 
             fileInfo.m_Identifier + Environment.NewLine + 
             fileInfo.m_TotalTime;
```

Answer (score 18):

A cleaner answer is:

Assuming txtStatus is a textbox:

```
txtStatus.Multiline = True;
txtStatus.Clear();
txtStatus.Text += "Line 1" + Environment.NewLine;
txtStatus.Text += "Line 2" + Environment.NewLine;
```

Using the built in enumeration means cleaner code.

Comment: In a wince7 c# app, there was no AppendText. So I had to use the += operation. Used "\r\n" for newline. Worked fine. 50 lines of text in a small multiline text box. Able to view all the text with the scroll bar.

Answer (score 12):

[Shift+Enter](http://jasonrshaver.com/blog/how-to-make-a-new-line-n-in-the-vs-resource-editor/)

```
In the Visual Studio resource editor, you can hit "Shift + Enter" 
to create a new line, as doing something like "\r\n" will get escaped 
out.  You will also need to increase the cell height to see both 
lines as it does not auto-size.
```

Comment: Does this really answer the question? Isn't this answer about something at design time, not at run time as in the question?

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing it programatically, append the new line to m_Txt.Lines, which is a string[].

```
m_Txt.Lines = new string[]{ fileInfo.m_Title, fileInfo.m_Identifier, fileInfo.m_TotalTime};
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why your code would not work unless something else is going on.

I just created a WinForms project using C#, added a textbox, set it multiline and added the following code - works a charm.

```
textBox1.Text = "a\r\nb";
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote this code, seems to be working fine.

```
public void setComments(String comments)
        {
            String[] aux;
            if(comments.Contains('\n')) //Multiple lines comments
            {
                aux = comments.Split('\n');
                for (int i = 0; i < aux.Length; i++)
                    this.textBoxComments.Text += aux[i] + Environment.NewLine;  
            }
            else //One line comments
                this.textBoxComments.Text = comments;
        }
```