# Cannot paste text to TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have problem with pasting data to textBox. I want to parse entered text to replace all newLines, but when I try to paste some text, let's say:

1234
5678
9000

I only get first line.
Is there any easy way or I have to somehow overwrite ctrl + v shortcut and parse what im trying to input?

Comment: `textbox.Multiline = true` that way you get more then the first line

Comment: Try use RichTextBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextBox accepts one line. If you want to copy all the texts, mentioned in your question, you should enable multiline in TextBox.

Or alternatively, the multiline version of TextBox is RichTextBox (Kudos to @EpicKip).

and I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927679/how-to-add-text-in-a-multiline-textbox) helps you handle it

Comment: There is no TextArea in winforms

Comment: TextArea you were speaking of is called RichTextBox in winforms. and also indeed multiline. But you were on the right track with TextArea :)

Comment: @EpicKip I am programming with Java and I thought that C(sharp) has also something like text area..

Comment: It does, RichTextBox :) you could add that to your answer :)

Comment: @EpicKip Yes, i have added :) Thanks.